# how can I clean up this javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two functions.

The first is well written because someone who knows how to write js did it.

The second I did.

```
var GetURLParameter = function($param){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == $param) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}


if(GetURLParameter('filter')!= "undefined"){
     $('#'+GetURLParameter('filter')).parent().parent().children('li.active').removeClass('active')
     $('#'+GetURLParameter('filter')).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

I would like to simplify the calls as I'm repeating the line `GetURLParameter('filter')` but I don't know how I can make it work like the key word `this`

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I only see one function here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stash the intermediate values in variables:

```
var $filter = GetURLParameter('filter');

if($filter != "undefined") { 
    var $parent = $('#' + GetURLParameter('filter')).parent();

    $parent.parent().children('li.active').removeClass('active');
    // better alternative (thanks wirey)
    // $parent.siblings('li.active').removeClass('active')

    $parent.addClass('active');
}
```

Of course this has the advantage of being more readable, and also it's more efficient because it doesn't re-rerun the same function or query the DOM multiple times.

Comment: only improvement would be `$parent.parent().children('li.active')` to `$parent.siblings('li.active')`

Answer (score 0):

// assuming that you have `ul`, you can also replace with `ol`

```
if(GetURLParameter('filter')!= "undefined"){    
    var $mydiv = $('#'+GetURLParameter('filter'));
    $mydiv.closest('ul').children('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $mydiv.parent().addClass('active');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function () {
   if( GetURLParameter( 'filter' ) != 'undefined' ) {
      var filter = $( '#' + GetURLParameter( 'filter' ) ).parent();
      filter.parent().children( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
      filter.addClass( 'active' );
   }
} );
```

Although I would say there are still more ways you could make this code better.